# Place div below overflowing child of previous div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I searched for this question but couldnt find it yet on SO (perhaps it also depends on the search query since this is a bit specific)

```
Div1
 |
  -- ChildDiv1
 |
Div2
```

Using Bootstrap 3. Div1 has a child (ChildDiv1) whose content overflows (and has `overflow:visible` set). All divs have `position:relative`

Now I want Div2 (which is the Footer) to appear *below* Div1/Child1 but it appears behind Child1 since overflow is set to visible. How can I have the Div2 automatically appear below whatever height Div1 and Child1 occupy?

Comment: I may come back with the code also, if needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `height:100%;` for Div1 helped.

Will post back if it does not work (i.e if breaks anything else etc.)